# Why is this Rails Minitest assert_equal failing with these Expected and Actual values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have;

- A Cart has_many Line_items.
- A Line_item belongs to a Cart.
- A Product has_many Line_items.
- A Line_item belongs to a product.

Upon a Post to line_items_path ,product_id is passed to line_items_controller#create (as below) within which cart#add_product is called (as below), which determines whether there's a line_item with the same product_id already present. If so, then the line_item.quantity of the existing line_item is increased by 1, if not then line_item.build then #save are called to create a whole new line item.

*line_items_controller.rb;*

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, product.price)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart } #, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.'
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

here is #add_product from *cart.rb*;

```
def add_product(product_id, product_price)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, price: product_price)
    end
    current_item
end
```

I am trying to test this functionality (via minitest) but am having trouble understanding the behavior that I see. My test is here;

*test/controllers/carts_*

```
test "should update quantity of existing line item when adding another of the same product" do
    cart = Cart.create 
    cart.add_product(products(:product_one).id, products(:product_one).price)
    cart.add_product(products(:product_one).id, products(:product_one).price)
    assert_equal cart.line_items.size, 1 
    # assert_equal cart.line_items[0].quantity, 2
  end
```

The test fails, reporting back;

```
Failure:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_update_quantity_of_existing_line_item_when_adding_another_of_the_same_product [AgileWebDev/depot/test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:73]:
Expected: 2
  Actual: 1
```

Which I cannot understand because

a) I have tested the behavior on the development server and viewed the tables through `psql` and it's behaving just as intended.

b) My test assertion; `assert_equal cart.line_items.size, 1` expects 1, so why does the Minitest error message state `Expected: 2`.

I am confused, after hours of head scratching and reading I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong here, can anybody help?

*Note - This is from the extra 'playtime' tasks defined at the end of Ch.10 of Agile Web Development with Rails 5'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) In your test case, there are no `line_items` in the cart since it is just created, so the line below will always return `nil`:

```
current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
```

therefore, the below line gets called twice, which causes the `line_items.size` to be 2:

```
current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, price: product_price)
```

You can use a cached variable to avoid it:

```
def add_product(product_id, product_price)
    @current_item ||= line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if @current_item
        @current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        @current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, price: product_price)
    end
    @current_item
end
```

b) According to the [Rails's Minitest](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-meets-minitest) introducing, the format of assertion should be

```
assert_equal( expected, actual, [msg] )
```

that why your assertion message goes wrong. The correct one is

```
assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size, "should has only 1 item"
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to part b: if you look at APIdocks for [assert_equal](https://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_equal), the expected value comes first, then the actual value. So the `1` you write is treated by Minitest as the actual value, while the expected value is `cart.line_items.size`

I am not sure why `cart.line_items.size` is equal to B. Assuming you are correct in your observations on your development server and in psql, it might have to do with the way your test conditions are set up. What happens if you add `assert_equal 0, cart.line_items.size` before the code where you add line-items, like this?

```
test "should update quantity of existing line item when adding another of the same product" do
    cart = Cart.create 
    assert_equal 0, cart.line_items.size
    cart.add_product(products(:product_one).id, products(:product_one).price)
    cart.add_product(products(:product_one).id, products(:product_one).price)
    assert_equal cart.line_items.size, 1 
    # assert_equal cart.line_items[0].quantity, 2
end
```